# SharePoint Modal for Document Upload: changing the Dialog options for Edit Form

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, modal-dialog, dialog-framework

So I am using the Upload.aspx for doc lib with GUID in order to have Upload at a custom spot on a page. I think its the edit form that pops up right after you upload a document to add the metadata. This is great and what I need, however there is one little piece I need some help with. If I set the options for the dialog I am using with the Upload.aspx the width and height stick for the edit form that pops open after and either way it looks bad. I either make a ridiculously large dialog for the upload to accomodate the edit, or visa versa.

So I am guessing there is a way to handle that in the callback, just not really sure.

Here is basically what I am calling from an onclick:

```
function openDialog() {
   var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
   dialogOptions.url = "server/site/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={GUID}&IsDlg=1";
   dialogOptions.width = 700  //works for the upload not for the edit
   dialogOptions.height = 185 //same as above; works for the upload
   dialogOptions.title = "My Title"
   dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallBack);
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); }

function CloseCallBack (result, returnValue) {
     if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
         // logic
     } else {
        // logic 
     }
```

Is there someway to remedy this? thanks as always for you help guys! always appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what you want to do is to change the size of the dialog when the upload.aspx is closed. Try this code

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

 var dlg = window.parent.SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
 dlg.$Q_0(800, 800); //width, height

}, "sp.ui.dialog.js");
```

Also, if you want to size the dialog automatically without specifying the height and width, use this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {

    //calling autoSize method will extend modal dialog beyond the size of the page
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().autoSize();
    //calling this obfuscated method will trim the dialog back within the page boundaries.
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().$2B_0();

}, "sp.ui.dialog.js");
```

Comment: @vardhaman....thanks! would i simply add the above inside the callback function (where the result is OK)? Or would this go with the initial function? I tried in both spots but can't seem to get it to work; perhaps I am just doing something wrong?

Comment: You will have to write this code on the EditForm.aspx which loads after the Upload.aspx has closed. Also, check out the updated code.

Comment: gotcha....so I could just use a CEWP and reference a text file with the above kind of thing? makes sense. thanks again for your help!

Comment: Or you could directly include the code in <script> tags on the page if you have access to SharePoint Designer.

Comment: works great! thanks for your help; greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)